# Whats the pythonic way to pass a variable into another class?

Tags: python

I have different classes which calculate different positions.

Lets say `ClassX` provides the function `get_xpos()` and `ClassY` therefore `get_ypos()`
For the calculation inside `ClassY` in need the `x_pos`.

I cant pass the value in the `__init__` function because it changes every cycle.
In C++ i would to this by passing a pointer..

Moving everything in one class is not possible for different reasons.

Right now im doing it like this:

```
class ClassY:
    y_pos = 0
    
    def simulate(self, x_pos):
        self.calc_y(x_pos)
```

every class has a simulate function to calculate the new values and a getter for the positions

main:

```
x = ClassX()
y = ClassY()

while True:
    x.simulate()
    y.simulate(x.get_xpos())
```

Note: the classes are in different files.

Comment: Do you really want y_pos to be a Class attribute or should it be an attribute of instances of the Class?

Comment: Does i matter whether i set `y_pos` like this or in the `__init__` with `self`? because in my calculation i´m accessing it with self.

Comment: Using self means that y_pos is related to (each) instance of the Class hence should be set within __init__. So then each instance has its own independent variable y_pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference to an instance of the ClassX to the constructor of ClassY. Then you can access the `x_pos` inside the `simulate` method of `y` without passing anything. Here's an example with `random x` and `y=2x`.

```py
import random

class ClassX:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_pos = 0
    
    def calc_x(self):
        self.x_pos = random.randint(0, 10)

    def simulate(self):
        self.calc_x()

class ClassY:
    def __init__(self, x_instance):
        self.x_instance = x_instance
        self.y_pos = 0
    
    def calc_y(self, x_pos):
        self.y_pos = x_pos * 2

    def simulate(self):
        self.calc_y(self.x_instance.x_pos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = ClassX()
    y = ClassY(x)

    for i in range(10):
        x.simulate()
        y.simulate()
        print(f"[{x.x_pos}, {y.y_pos}]")
```

Comment: It is important to note (since OP explicitly mentioned that usecase) that `y.x_instance.x_pos` will always "see" the most recent value even if it is changed via `x.x_pos = ...` because Python uses a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case where you may want to read up on [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:%7E:text=Dependency%20injection%20aims%20to%20separate,how%20to%20construct%20those%20services.). It would seem that ClassY depends on ClassX, so why not pass the X instance in the constructor (**init**) of ClassY? As long as ClassX has a stable interface on providing get_xpos() you'll be fine (maybe you'll also want to read on up [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) - specifically the Open-closed principle here)